# Processing xml file VS. processing excel file from .Net

Tags: xml, excel

I would like to ask what should be faster: reading excel file from .Net or reading xml file which contains the same data. The same is for writing.

Thank you very much in advance.

mayap.

Answer (score 1):

The smaller the file, the faster it will be read.

However, in .NET, it is easier to use XML with the classes of the BCL (Base Class Library) as there is no excel support built in.

You can use [Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query the XML structure and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer for that question. There are too many variables and you should try it yourself with the options available to you and with a representative data set (xml file, xls / xlsx workbook, ???).

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) provides a fast API for reading (and creating / modifying / rendering / writing / etc...) Excel workbooks from .NET. You can see live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC